# What are these things called?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary, nouns

I recently went on a trip to Peru, and met some pre-inca people. They braid their long hair into two ponytails, and weave balls of cotton to the end of the ponytail. What are those called? Bon-bons or something like that?[image: pic]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are those called? Bon-bons or something like that?

I think you might be mixing up *pompons* and *bonbons*.

A *[bonbon](https://www.wordnik.com/words/bonbon)* is a piece of candy, often covered in chocolate.

A [*pompon*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/pompom) is an ornamental woolen ball.

The word *pompon* in English can also be spelled *pompom* or *pom-pom*.

For what it's worth, I found these images on Google by search for *pompons* and *bonbons*:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You phonetic memory wasn't far off: The word you are looking for is probably "pom-pom" (not bon-bon).

But I agree with Dmandy, you could also call them "tassels".

Answer (score 2):

Bon-Bons are two buns on the either side of the head

These look more like tassels

Comment: **Tassel** suggests that the strings hang down from a knotted ball at the top, not tied into a ball at the bottom. Take a look at these [images of tassels](https://www.google.com/search?q=tassel&tbm=isch).